# select dropdown value depending first dropdown value in codeigniter php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

This is my view file here i use 5 search field like product, group, branch, startdate and end date. All are placed in different table. Both were worked nicely and searched nicely but now i want some additional option that is when i select a particular branch in group field dynamically show values based on branch field value. Now it is showing whole data in db.

> NOTE: i want this change appear when dropdown select.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <form method="get" id="frmSearchGroupPur" action="<?php echo 
  base_url('admin/group/listgroup'); ?>">
            <div class="form-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" 
   style="text-align: left">Product</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <?php
                                $product = array();
  //                                    if($data['products']){
  //                                        foreach ($data['products'] as 
  $p) 
  {
 //                                            $product[$p['id']] = 
  $p['name'];
  //                                        }
 //                                    }
                                echo form_dropdown('product', $product, 
 $data['product'], array('class' => 'form-control 
 select2','id'=>'product'));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" 
   style="text-align: left">Branch</label>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <?php
                                $branch = array(NULL=>'Any');
                                if($data['branches']){
                                    foreach ($data['branches'] as $w){
                                        $branch[$w['id']] = $w['name'];
                                    }
                                }
                                echo form_dropdown('branch', $branch, 
 $data['branch'], array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'branch_dat'));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" 
   style="text-align: left">Group</label>
                             <div class="col-md-7">
                                <?php
                                $group = array(NULL=>'Any');
                                if($data['groups']){
                                    foreach ($data['groups'] as $g){
                                        $group[$g->id] = $g->name;
                                    }
                                }
                                echo form_dropdown('group', $group, 
  $data['group'], array('class' => 'form-control'));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><br/>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" 
 style="text-align: left">Purchase Date From</label>
                            <div class='input-group date col-md-7' 
id='datetimepicker6'>
                                <?php echo 
 form_input('fromdate',$data['fromdate'],array('class' => 'form- 
 control','id'=>'fromdate')); ?>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
 calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" 
  style="text-align: left">Purchase Date To</label>
                            <div class='input-group date col-md-7' 
 id='datetimepicker7'>
                                <?php echo 
  form_input('todate',$data['todate'],array('class' => 'form- 
 control','id'=>'todate')); ?>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group pull-center">
                            <button type="submit" id="btnFilter" class="btn 
     btn-info">Submit</button>
                            <a href="<?php echo 
    base_url('admin/group/listgroup'); ?>" class="btn btn-default">Reset</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>
```

and my model file to get group is

```
 function getGroupDetails($groupid=0,$state=''){
    $this->db->where('id',$groupid);
    $this->db->where('branchid',$state);
    $query = $this->db->get('group');
    if($query->num_rows()==1){
        return $query->row_array();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

and my controller function is

```
 function get_group(){
    $state=$this->input->post('brch');
   $result = $this->model_group->getGroupDetails($state);
  // echo json_decode($result);
   }
```

and my not worked jquery file to change group dynamically is below

```
  $('branch_dat').change(function(){
  var branch_da=$('#branch_dat').val();
  if(branch_da != "")
  {
  var post_url="admin/sale/get_group";
   $('branch_dat').change(function(){
   var branch_da=$('#branch_dat').val();
  if(branch_da != "")
  {
 var post_url="admin/sale/get_group";
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:post_url,
  data:function(params)
  {
    return{ brch : params.brch};
  }
  });
  }
  });
```

Comment: What you get after ajax call? And where is your code after ajax done?

Comment: nothing any moment

Comment: it's show all group field in DB

Comment: Add that ajax return in the question and show what you tried so far.

Comment: i doesn't use any ajax return

Comment: @CodeThing now look above code i was edit

Comment: Sorry this is not what i meant. I want to see what your params variable has when ajax is completed. First of all your jquery call will not run as you just are just adding change handler for 'branch_dat'. It should be `#branch_dat`